# Received message of type (resize) before initialization

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm loading iframe-resizer using:

```
var isOldIE = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1);
iFrameResize({log: true, autoResize: true, minHeight: 67, checkOrigin: false, heightCalculationMethod: isOldIE ? 'max' : 'lowestElement'}, '#my-iframe');
```

But I keep getting this error when resizing the page:

> [iFrameSizer][] Received message of type (resize) before
>   initialization.

This comes after:

> [iFrameSizer][Host page] IFrame scrolling disabled for qb-iframe
>
> iframeResizer.js:97[iFrameSizer][Host page] Set minHeight = 67px
>
> iframeResizer.js:97[iFrameSizer][Host page][init] Sending msg to
>   iframe
>   (qb-iframe:8:false:true:32:false:true:null:lowestElement:null:null:0:false:parent)
>
> [iFrameSizer][Host page][iFrame.onload] Sending msg to iframe
>   (qb-iframe:8:false:true:32:false:true:null:lowestElement:null:null:0:false:parent)
>
> [iFrameSizer][Host page][Window resize] Sending msg to iframe (resize)

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have a link. And I forgot to mention that resizing doesn't work. The extra content just gets cut off.

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning message rather than an error. You can safely ignore it. In the next release it will be a standard log message and made a bit clear.